# htaccess rewrite 2 rule Simultaneously

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I hava an htaccess file.it pass url to index.php

```
<!-- language-all: lang-html -->
RewriteEngine On    

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l    
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

now i wanna to remove "www" befor my domain name and also keep my previous RewriteRule .
How to do it؟ 
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a new rule for www removel **before** your current rule:

```
RewriteEngine On    

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l    
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```